# NotFittedError (instance is not fitted yet) after invoked cross_validate

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

This is my minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

x = np.array([
   [1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6],
   [6, 7]
])  
y = [1, 0, 0, 1]

model = GaussianNB()
scores = cross_validate(model, x, y, cv=2, scoring=("accuracy"))

model.predict([8,9])
```

What I intended to do is instantiating a [Gaussian Naive Bayes Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) and use [sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) for cross validate my model (I am using `cross_validate` instead of `cross_val_score` since in my real project I need precision, recall and f1 as well).

I have read in the doc that `cross_validate` does "evaluate metric(s) by cross-validation and also record fit/score times."

I expected that my `model` would have been fitted on `x` (features), `y` (labels) data but when I invoke `model.predict(.)` I get:

> sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This GaussianNB instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Of course it says me about invoking `model.fit(x,y)` before "using the estimator" (that is before invoking `model.predict(.)`.

Shouldn't the model have been fitted `cv=2` times when I invoke `cross_validate(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close look at `cross_validate` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) reveals that it includes an argument:

> **return_estimator : *bool, default=False***
>
> Whether to return the estimators fitted on each split.

So, by default it will not return any fitted estimator (hence it cannot be used to `predict`).

In order to predict with the fitted estimator(s), you need to set the argument to `True`; but beware, you will **not** get a *single* fitted model, but a number of models equal to your `cv` parameter value (here 2):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

x = np.array([
   [1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6],
   [6, 7]
])  
y = [1, 0, 0, 1]

model = GaussianNB()
scores = cross_validate(model, x, y, cv=2, scoring=("accuracy"), return_estimator=True)
scores
# result:
{'fit_time': array([0.00124454, 0.00095725]),
 'score_time': array([0.00090432, 0.00054836]),
 'estimator': [GaussianNB(), GaussianNB()],
 'test_score': array([0.5, 0.5])}
```

So, in order to get predictions from each fitted model, you need:

```
scores['estimator'][0].predict([[8,9]])
# array([1])

scores['estimator'][1].predict([[8,9]])
# array([0])
```

This may look inconvenient, but it is like that by design: `cross_validate` is generally meant only to return the scores necessary for diagnosis and assessment, not to be used for fitting models which are to be used for predictions.

Comment: @tail no; as said, this is by design: with `cross_validate`, you can only get back as many models as your `cv` folds. There are other CV tools available in scikit-learn that return a final fitted model, like [`GridSearcgCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there any chance I can get one (1) model instead of k models? If not, which estimator am I supposed to choose for predicting labels for unseen data?

Comment: @tail I have already answered that above (please refrain from deleting comments that have been already answered). You **don't want** to use **any** of the estimators returned by `cross_validate` for predictions, since by definition they are not trained on the whole of your data; as said, `cross_validate` is not meant for such usage.

Comment: May I use GridSearchCV for having one (1) "final" estimator, then?

Comment: @tail `GridSearchCV`, used with the default argument `refit=True`, will indeed return a single model fitted with all the data. Please check the docs (link in my 1st comment above).

Comment: GridSearchCV does require a param param_grid

Comment: @tail please notice that the answer addressed fully your original question on why you get an error with your approach; it has nothing to do with GridSearchCV or any other issues not present in your original post. If you have a new question, please open a new post - we cannot guess what exactly you are trying to do from such fragmented conversation in the comments (1/2)

Comment: In any case, especially for `GaussianNB` (which has actually **no** tunable parameters), it does not make any sense to use `GridSearchCV` - you just fit the model with all your data and you are fine, after you have used `cross_validate` in order to get a performance assessment. (2/2)

Comment: Actually GaussianNB has var_smoothing float, default=1e-9
Portion of the largest variance of all features that is added to variances for calculation stability. Can't I use grid search CV for tuning that hyperparam?

Comment: @tail you sure can, at least in theory; not sure how relevant it is in practice though - but again I have almost zero experience with GaussianNB. The experiment is arguably your best friend here.