pipeline.predict NotFittedError using cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
    ('classifier', LogisticRegression())  
])

X_train, y_train = load_iris(return_X_y=True)  
cv_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, cv=5)

X_test, y_test = load_iris(return_X_y=True) 
test_predictions = pipeline.predict(X_test) 

The error I get is :
NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.


I was under the impression that using cross_val_score with the estimator would automatically call fit on the estimator, what should be the solution in this case?
I have considered pipeline.fit() before I do cross_val_score but that seems redundant to me? Am I wrong?

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263915/using-sklearn-cross-val-score-and-kfolds-to-fit-and-help-predict-model and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715460/notfittederror-instance-is-not-fitted-yet-after-invoked-cross-validate

I think your first message, first link answers my question, thank you.
